# How to add JavaScript object data to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, csv

I'm using PAPA parser to parse a .csv file and the file looks like this in Chrome debug tools.

```
       [Object]
data: Array[4]
    0: Array[5]
    0: "title"
    1: "summary_text"
    2: "date"
    3: "type"
    4: "link"
    length: 5
    __proto__: Array[0]
    1: Array[5]
    0: "Choice, Happiness and Spaghetti Sauce"
    1: "Delivering product variety: chunky spaghetti sauce, zesty pickles, or weak coffee? Gladwell explains how the root of happy customers is product variety."
    2: "30-Jan-13"
    3: "sm"
    4: "https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?id=380939405308665&story_fbid=298838986905013"
    length: 5
    __proto__: Array[0]
    2: Array[5]
    3: Array[1]
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array[0]
    errors: Array[0]
    meta: Object
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: jQuery[0]
```

With this I want to be able to extract the title, link, date and type and put all this into an `<li>` tag. How can I achieve this? I was able to parse the data and I get this and I am able to paste all the data into the HTML by using `JSON.stringify(r2, null, 4);`.

I want to loop through the data parent and get all the child title, dates, descriptions, type, etc.. and add these to an li tag.

Would it look something like right?

```
Papa.parse("http://support.jonar.com/support/default.asp?pg=pgDownload&pgType=pgWikiAttachment&ixAttachment=142896&sFileName=newsroom.csv", {
    download: true,
    complete: function(results) {
            //console.log("REMOTE FILE PARSED!", results.data);
                var r2 = $(results);
                //var r3 = JSON.stringify(r2, null, 4);
                //console.log(r2)
                $('ul.nflist').append( $('<li />', {text: results}));
    }
});
```

Comment: A simple for loop will do it. Read more about objects here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function(results) {
    $.each(results.data.slice(1), // skip first row of CSV headings
        function(i, data) {
            var title = data[0];
            var link = data[4];
            var date = data[2];
            var type = data[3];
            $('ul.nflist').append($('<li>', {
                html: '<a href="' + link + '">' + title + '</a> ' + date + ' ' + type
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar It worked... the problem is it only does one of them it loops through only data [0] there are 3 more... It worked great i just need to look through all the childs of data. There are 3 and then the data is there... How can i achieve this..

Comment: `results.data.slice(1)` should loop through all of them. I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: hi @Barmar how can i filter the data to only show rows that contain `sm` as the type?

Comment: Use `if (type == 'sm')` around the call `$('ul.nflist').append()`.

Comment: sorry @barmar i did not understand my friend what do you mean around the call?

Comment: This is beginner programming `if (type == 'sm') { $('ul.nflist').append(...); }`

Comment: The same way you do anything else depending on the value of a variable.

Comment: that's what i understood sorry i was not sure! thank you for clearing that up. @Barmar

Comment: Hey @barbar sorry to bother again but using this it is able to catch the rows that contain `sm` but it only returns the first row that contains `sm` and not the others...

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would do that. Can you create a jsfiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work because of the AJAX same-origin rule. But when I try downloading `http://support.jonar.com/support/default.asp?pg=pgDownload&pgType=pgWikiAttachment&ixAttachment=142924&sFileName=newsroom.csv` by hand, it's empty.

Comment: yes the  website has securities you must be logged in to download files i hosted it here for you http://www.filedropper.com/newsroom

Comment: That file only has one row. What other rows are you expecting the code to display?

Comment: sorry i have so many of these files i hate working with data and jquery! so hard!! http://www.filedropper.com/newsroom5 thats the correct one

Comment: You're removing the second one with this line: `$('ul.nflist li:last-child').remove();`

Comment: Since there are only two lines with `type = sm`, removing the last one just leaves the first one.

Comment: Thank you @Barbar for the continuous support.. You really provided me with good information and i wish there was another way for me to give you more recognition for your help on the community! Thanks buddy.

Comment: do you know why this works `var link = date[1]` but this does not `var link = data.link`

Comment: Because `data` is an array, not an object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89858/discussion-between-user2752291-and-barmar).